# ThinkPad T450 reboots after shutdown

Tags: suspend, power-management, thinkpad, acpi

I am trying to debug what I suspect to be a hardware issue. In short my ThinkPad T450 instantly reboots on shutdown and wakes up on suspend.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, I have disabled everything in proc/acpi/wakeup and also set the contents of every "wakeup" file on the system to "disabled".

proc/acpi/wakeup config:

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
LID       S4    *disabled  platform:PNP0C0D:00
SLPB      S3    *disabled  platform:PNP0C0E:00
IGBE      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:19.0
EXP2      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.1
XHCI      S3    *disabled
EHC1      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
```

The problem still persists, the following is the dmesg after a wakeup from suspend:

```
[ 2457.839062] PM: Suspending system (mem)
[ 2457.839093] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 2457.960532] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 2457.978970] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[ 2458.191440] e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
[ 2458.479145] PM: suspend of devices complete after 640.058 msecs
[ 2458.499220] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 20.073 msecs
[ 2458.519513] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 20.296 msecs
[ 2458.519784] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[ 2458.630971] ACPI : EC: EC stopped
[ 2458.630971] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[ 2458.630976] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 2458.631247] Broke affinity for irq 23
[ 2458.632277] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[ 2458.643511] Broke affinity for irq 23
[ 2458.643515] Broke affinity for irq 41
[ 2458.643517] Broke affinity for irq 43
[ 2458.644543] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[ 2458.655495] Broke affinity for irq 1
[ 2458.655505] Broke affinity for irq 9
[ 2458.655511] Broke affinity for irq 12
[ 2458.655517] Broke affinity for irq 23
[ 2458.655523] Broke affinity for irq 41
[ 2458.655526] Broke affinity for irq 43
[ 2458.655529] Broke affinity for irq 47
[ 2458.656573] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[ 2458.668259] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[ 2458.668311] ACPI : EC: EC started
[ 2458.668312] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[ 2458.668671] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 2458.688473] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[ 2458.688474] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
[ 2458.692074]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[ 2458.692160] CPU1 is up
[ 2458.708487] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x2
[ 2458.711962]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[ 2458.712048] CPU2 is up
[ 2458.728505] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[ 2458.732253]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[ 2458.732348] CPU3 is up
[ 2458.735547] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[ 2458.964274] acpi LNXPOWER:02: Turning OFF
[ 2458.988867] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 16.592 msecs
[ 2458.994388] PM: early resume of devices complete after 5.504 msecs
[ 2458.995131] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[ 2458.995443] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 2458.995570] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[ 2459.224177] usb 1-1.6: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 2459.388135] usb 1-1.8: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 2459.520171] PM: resume of devices complete after 525.960 msecs
[ 2459.520352] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[ 2459.520353] Restarting tasks ... done.
[ 2459.730565] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5676], y [..4758]
[ 2459.758966] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1266..], y [1096..]
[ 2460.599743] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 2460.908472] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[ 2460.908477] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[ 2460.908479] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[ 2460.965214] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[ 2460.965218] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[ 2460.965220] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[ 2460.991587] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
```

I cannot see anything obvious from this. Is there any way to get more granularity to find out **exactly** what is causing the wake up from suspension?

I feel whatever is causing the system to wake up is also causing it to reboot on shutdown. I just need to find out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a late answer but I did solve my issue in the end and wanted to type up my resolution here, in case anyone comes across it again.

So to recap my ThinkPad T450 would not shutdown permanently, every-time I shut it down, either through the OS or the power button, it would instantly reboot.

If I held the power button down for an extended period I would hear a click and the laptop would power off completely but when trying to power it on I would get the classic ThinkPad blinking power LED. In this state to boot the laptop up I would have to disconnect the CMOS for a minute or two, then on reconnection I would be able to boot again but the eternal shutdown/reboot cycle would begin anew.

**My Solution**

1. Power the laptop on.
2. During POST/BIOS screen hold down the power button long enough for the laptop to shutdown but not long enough to trigger the state where the CMOS needs resetting.
3. The laptop will instantly reboot after powering down.
4. Again during POST/BIOS hold down the power button to shutdown (but not for too long!).
5. Keep repeating this cycle of powering down the laptop until it eventually remains off. And hopefully it wont be in the CMOS requires resetting state described above.

This is what I did, after powering down maybe 4 or 5 times it eventually remained off. I have been able to boot and shutdown normally now for over a year and have not seen this issue return.

If anyone has any idea what the issue was here I would love to know.